# Google Drive API v3 create and upload file

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I have a python script that creates a Google Drive file via API and uploads it. I am trying to rewrite the script in Go but the API documentation does not provide a Go quickstart. Here is the python script:

```
#!/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

try:
 import argparse
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ebay Google Drive Uploader')
 parser.add_argument('-r', metavar="rack",
  help="-r <rack>")
except ImportError:
 parser = None

try:
 args = parser.parse_args()
except:
 print (parser.error)
#print ("parser = ", parser)

if not args.r:
 print ("Please specify rack (-r rack)")
 exit
else:
 #print ("Processing ", args.r)
 sheet_name = args.r + ".csv"
 sheet_filename = '/tmp/' + args.r + '.csv'

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Ebay Google Drive Uploader - albraden@ebay.com'


def get_credentials():
 """Gets valid user credentials from storage.
 Returns:
  Credentials, the obtained credential.
 """
 home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
 credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
 if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
  os.makedirs(credential_dir)
 credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
  'drive-python-quickstart.json')

 store = Storage(credential_path)
 credentials = store.get()
 if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
  print ("before flow\n")
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
  print ("flow = ", flow)
  flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
  if parser:
   credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, parser)
  else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
   credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
  print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
 return credentials

def main():
 """Creates a spreadsheet using the Google Drive API
 """
 credentials = get_credentials()
 http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
 service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

 file_metadata = {
  'name' : sheet_name,
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
 }
 media = MediaFileUpload(sheet_filename,
  mimetype='text/csv')
 results  = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                   media_body=media,
                                   fields='id').execute()

 sheet_id = results["id"]
 print (sheet_id)
 #sheet_url = results["webViewLink"]
 #print ('sheet_url = ', sheet_url)
 def callback(request_id, response, exception):
  if exception:
   # Handle error
   print (exception)
  #else:
   #print ("Permission Id: %s" % response.get('id'))

 batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
 domain_permission = {
  'type': 'domain',
  'role': 'writer',
  'domain': 'ebay.com',
  'allowFileDiscovery': True
 }
 batch.add(service.permissions().create(
  fileId=sheet_id,
  body=domain_permission,
  fields='id',
 ))
 batch.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify the media type. In Python I used MediaFileUpload but it looks like Golang requires a different method. Here's what I have in Go:

```
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 "io/ioutil"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "net/url"
 "os"
 "os/user"
 "path/filepath"

 "golang.org/x/net/context"
 "golang.org/x/oauth2"
 "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
 "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
)

// getClient uses a Context and Config to retrieve a Token
// then generate a Client. It returns the generated Client.
func getClient(ctx context.Context, config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
 cacheFile, err := tokenCacheFile()
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to get path to cached credential file. %v", err)
 }
 tok, err := tokenFromFile(cacheFile)
 if err != nil {
  tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
  saveToken(cacheFile, tok)
 }
 return config.Client(ctx, tok)
}

// getTokenFromWeb uses Config to request a Token.
// It returns the retrieved Token.
func getTokenFromWeb(config *oauth2.Config) *oauth2.Token {
 authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
 fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
  "authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

 var code string
 if _, err := fmt.Scan(&code); err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code %v", err)
 }

 tok, err := config.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web %v", err)
 }
 return tok
}

// tokenCacheFile generates credential file path/filename.
// It returns the generated credential path/filename.
func tokenCacheFile() (string, error) {
 usr, err := user.Current()
 if err != nil {
  return "", err
 }
 tokenCacheDir := filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".credentials")
 os.MkdirAll(tokenCacheDir, 0700)
 return filepath.Join(tokenCacheDir,
  url.QueryEscape("drive-go-quickstart.json")), err
}

// tokenFromFile retrieves a Token from a given file path.
// It returns the retrieved Token and any read error encountered.
func tokenFromFile(file string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
 f, err := os.Open(file)
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 t := &oauth2.Token{}
 err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(t)
 defer f.Close()
 return t, err
}

// saveToken uses a file path to create a file and store the
// token in it.
func saveToken(file string, token *oauth2.Token) {
 fmt.Printf("Saving credential file to: %s\n", file)
 f, err := os.OpenFile(file, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to cache oauth token: %v", err)
 }
 defer f.Close()
 json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(token)
}

func main() {
 ctx := context.Background()
 b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/usr/local/lib/client_secret.json")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
 }

 // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 // at ~/.credentials/drive-go-quickstart.json
 config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveFileScope)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
 }
 client := getClient(ctx, config)

 srv, err := drive.New(client)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve drive Client %v", err)
 }

 file_metadata := make(map[string]string)
 sheet_name := "SLC:SLC02:02-314:06:04.csv"
 sheet_filename := "/tmp/SLC:SLC02:02-314:06:04.csv"
 file_metadata["name"] = sheet_name
 file_metadata["mimeType"] = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
 media = MediaFileUpload(sheet_filename, mimetype="text/csv")


 r, err := srv.Files.Create(body=file_metadata,
                            media_body=media,
                            fields='id')
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to create file: %v", err)
 }
}
```

Can someone provide a working example that creates and uploads a document to Google Drive?

Reference links are here: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/JmElgduugSKLVSAYm1htGw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample script? This sample was modified `main()` of your script. When you use this sample, please replace your `main()` to mine. In your Python script, it converts from CSV to Spreadsheet and modify the permissions. So also it gave the same flow to this sample.

### Important points :

1. Give mimeType of file that it wants to upload to `options` of `Media(r io.Reader, options ...googleapi.MediaOption)`.
2. In order to give `options`, use `googleapi.ContentType()`.
3. Give mimeType of file that it wants to convert, when it uploads it to Google Drive, to `file` of `Create(file *File)`.
4. In order to give `file`, use `&drive.File{}`.
5. For installing permissions, use `&drive.Permission{}`. Each parameter is the same to them for Python.

### Sample script :

```
func main1() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/usr/local/lib/client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-go-quickstart.json
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveFileScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(ctx, config)

    srv, err := drive.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve drive Client %v", err)
    }

    //  I modified below.
    sheet_name := "SLC:SLC02:02-314:06:04.csv"                     // File you want to upload on Google Drive
    sheet_filename := "/tmp/SLC:SLC02:02-314:06:04.csv"            // File you want to upload on your PC
    baseMimeType := "text/csv"                                     // mimeType of file you want to upload
    convertedMimeType := "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" // mimeType of file you want to convert on Google Drive

    file, err := os.Open(sheet_filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    f := &drive.File{
        Name:     sheet_name,
        MimeType: convertedMimeType,
    }
    res, err := srv.Files.Create(f).Media(file, googleapi.ContentType(baseMimeType)).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s, %s, %s\n", res.Name, res.Id, res.MimeType)

    permissiondata := &drive.Permission{
        Type:               "domain",
        Role:               "writer",
        Domain:             "ebay.com",
        AllowFileDiscovery: true,
    }
    pres, err := srv.Permissions.Create(res.Id, permissiondata).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", pres.Type, pres.Role)
}
```

### Result :

```
SLC:SLC02:02-314:06:04.csv, ### file ID on Google Drive ###, application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
domain, writer
```

### References :

Also I got the infomation for this sample from godoc and GitHub of google-api-go-client.

- Files.Create : [godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3#FilesCreateCall) and [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/v3/drive-gen.go#L3996)
- Permissions.Create : [godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3#Permission) and [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/v3/drive-gen.go#L1388)

#### Edit :

This uses [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/go). In order to use this sample script, please do the Step 1 and Step 2.

Or your library may be required to update.

At this sample script, it works file using `google-api-go-client/drive/v3/` of Sep 13, 2017.

Comment: When I try to run this I get an error: undefined: googleapi in googleapi.ContentType  - How do I define googleapi?

Comment: @Albert Braden I'm sorry for the inconvenience. The error means that the library is not installed on your PC. This uses [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/go). Please do the Step 1 and Step 2. If your library is old, please update it. And I updated my answer, please confirm it.

Comment: Found it, it is "google.golang.org/api/googleapi" - not included in the quickstart.

Comment: @Albert Braden I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Albert Braden Welcome. Thank you, too.